# How to backup faunadb collection?

Tags: backup, json

I want to migrate my faunadb collection to a different database, how can I download all data in collection in a JSON format ?

Answer (score 0):

Create Index for collection with `Terms` field as empty (so we will get all objects in database without any filtering), and fetch all data inside collection using that index as follows:

```js
import faunadb from 'faunadb'
const q = faunadb.query
import fs from 'fs'


const client0 = new faunadb.Client({
  secret: '<secret-key>',
  domain: 'db.us.fauna.com', // put to correct configuration for your database
  port: 443,
  scheme: 'https',
})


const backupFaunadb = async (indexName, pageSize, noOfPages) => {

  let after = []     // cursor to move to next page
  try {
    for (let i = 0; i < noOfPages; i++) {
      if (after === undefined) break    // stop after last page
      const result = await client0.query(
        q.Map(
          q.Paginate(q.Match(q.Index(indexName)), { size: pageSize, after }),
          q.Lambda('param1', q.Get(q.Var('param1')))  // here word 'param1' is random-word
        )
      )
      after = result.after
      console.log(after)
      const result0 = result.data.map(obj => obj.data)
      const result1 = JSON.stringify(result0, null, 2)

      await fs.promises.writeFile(`./${indexName}-${i}.json`, result1)
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

const backupSolanaVault = async () => {
  const pageSize = 50, noOfPages = 5
  const promisesArr = [
    backupFaunadb('all_telegraph', pageSize, noOfPages),
  ]
  await Promise.all(promisesArr)
}

backupSolanaVault()
```